# Foreigner flying within the US without a passport

Tags: usa, air-travel, passports

Can I travel by plane from California to Colorado without an up-to-date passport?

Comment: Your title says *without password*, your question text says  *without* **updated** *password*. What is it? And what do you mean with an 'updated' password anyway? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @RoboKaren there is no indication that the person asking this question is a foreigner.  Rather than making the question into something it isn't, it seems to me that it is better to answer it without regard to the ambiguity, as WGroleau did, or to vote to close it as unclear.  In any event, the question is a duplicate; it's just not possible to know what it's a duplicate of without knowing the asker's nationality.

Comment: See [Flying within the United States, Passport required?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2686/19400) and [Travelling within the US as a foreign citizen without a passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10226/19400) and any of several other similar questions in the "Related" section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travelling within the US as a foreign citizen without a passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/travelling-within-the-us-as-a-foreign-citizen-without-a-passport)

Answer (score 4):

You need some form of ID that meets the "real ID" requirements.  Driver's license in most states can be used (last I heard, only four states did not comply).

For other options, read the [Real ID FAQs](https://www.dhs.gov/real-id-public-faqs) or the [**many** other questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=real%20ID) on this topic.

Comment: All states either are in compliance or have an extension.  The only US jurisdiction that does not have an extension is American Samoa.  See https://www.dhs.gov/real-id.  It's worth noting that the only acceptable non-US driver's licenses are those from Canada, and the only acceptable non-Canadian foreign document is a passport.  Documents are only acceptable if they are valid.  See https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification.  However, there are procedures for flying without acceptable identification.

Comment: Does the extension mean they must comply but are given more time, or does it mean that their non-enhanced licenses are accepted for a longer time?  In other words, is it a concession to the state or to the traveler?  (Rhetorical; the FAQ makes it a concession for the traveler's convenience.)

Comment: Note that the FAQ “Is DHS trying to build a national database with all of our information?” is disingenuous at best.  I have no idea whether they are trying to build a DB with "_all_ of our information" but they certainly are keeping track of our travels.  And at least one person who successfully coerced them into giving him his own file found full credit card numbers in it.

Comment: I believe the extension means both of those things.  Certainly, licenses from states with extensions are accepted, and I presume that a condition for being granted an extension is a viable plan to achieve compliance.

Comment: I missed the word “foreigner” in the title, or else it was added after I answered.  A foreigner would not likely have a driver’s license from one of our states.  But then, if he got in legally, why wouldn’t the passport be valid?

Comment: The word "foreigner" was added to the title after you answered.  Many foreigners have US driver's licenses.  Some foreigners stay so long that their passports expire; there's no requirement for green card holders to maintain a valid passport, for example.